# How to set kendo datepicker date?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am using kendo datetimepicker but i am not able to get the custom date on html

this is html

```
<input id="datepicker" ng-model="valid_to" style="width: 100%" kendodate/>
```

this is directive

```
myApp.directive('kendodate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var start = elem.kendoDatePicker({format: "yyyy/MM/dd"});

        }
    }
})
```

this is the controller

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.valid_to = new Date('10-11-2015');
});
```

how to show this date of controller in html?

Comment: invalid date is coming in directive!

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive, You need to pass the date defined in your controller. i.e. You need to access the `ng-model` in the directive. Then you can pass its to `kendoDatePicker` using value config.

```
myApp.directive('kendodate', function() {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl || ngModelCtrl.$modelValue) return;
            var start = elem.kendoDatePicker({format: "yyyy/MM/dd", value : ngModelCtrl.$modelValue});    
        }
    }
})
```